# How to use LinkedBlockingQueue to run tasks

Tags: java, threadpool, blockingqueue

I am currently trying to get my code to print what is in the method of simpleTask 20 times using the code in simpleTesting. The idea is that simpleTesting adds 20 instances of simpleTask to a queue then they are taken from the queue in simplePoolThread. What should happen is that it prints out the testing message 20 times then continues to run while looking for more things from the queue (but there are none). Instead it is currently just not printing anything and continuously running. Here is my code (a lot of it is interfaces, I believe the problem lies in the simpleThreadPool code):

```
package simpleThreadPool;

/**
 *   <<-- Pool Thread -->> 
 *
 *   It will be running continuously. It will try to retrieve new tasks when it is idle. 
 */
public interface ISimplePoolThread extends Runnable {
    /**
     *   Use an infinite loop to retrieve and perform tasks.
     */
    @Override
    public void run();
}
```

.

```
package simpleThreadPool;

/**
 *   <<-- Simple Task -->> 
 *
 *   ISimpleTask is to be performed by PoolThread. 
 */
public interface ISimpleTask{
    /**
     *   #1. Create a class to implement ISimpleTask, put content of the task to method run().
     */
    public void run();
}
```

.

```
    package simpleThreadPool;


    /**
     *   <<-- Thread Pool -->> 
     *   It manages a queue of tasks, starts some pool threads.
     *      
     *   #1. Create a task queue by using queue data structures, or designing your own data structure. 
     */
    public interface ISimpleThreadPool {

        /**
         *   #1. Initialize your queue (or do so in somewhere)
         *   #2. Starts some ISimplePoolThreads.
         */
        public void start();

        /**
         *   #1. Stops everything
         */
        public void stop();

        /**
         *   #1. Add a task to your queue.
         */
        public void addTask(ISimpleTask task);
    }
```

.

```
    package simpleThreadPool;

public class SimpleTask implements ISimpleTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("testing testing 1 2 3");
    }
}
```

.
I think the problem lies in this piece of code, where the tasks are taken from the queue:

```
package simpleThreadPool;

import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class SimplePoolThread implements ISimplePoolThread, Runnable {


    private LinkedBlockingQueue<ISimpleTask> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Inserting Element: ");
            try {
                queue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

.

```
package simpleThreadPool;

import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class SimpleThreadPool implements ISimpleThreadPool {

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<ISimpleTask> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    @Override
    public void start() {
        (new Thread(new SimplePoolThread())).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        try {
            queue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addTask(ISimpleTask task) { 

        try {
            queue.put(task);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

.

the testing file:

```
package simpleThreadPool;

public class SimpleTesting implements ISimpleTask{

    private int i;

    public SimpleTesting(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        // Initialize thread pool
        SimpleThreadPool pool = new SimpleThreadPool();
        pool.start();
        // Create 20 tasks
        for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++){
            pool.addTask(new SimpleTesting(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task queue in your SimplePoolThread is a blocking queue.  As soon as it starts it executes queue.take().  Take is a blocking operation.  The thread sits there waiting forever until something else adds a task into the queue.

Your hunch on the problem location was pretty close.  The issue is that the queue in SimplePoolThread and the queue in SimpleThreadPool are not the same; you have two separate queues.  So when SimpleTesting adds tasks they go into Pool's queue and NOT into the Thread's queue.  So the thread will sit there forever waiting on nothing.  You also forgot to actually run your tasks inside of SimplePoolThread.

Try the following instead.

```
public class SimpleThreadPool implements ISimpleThreadPool {

private LinkedBlockingQueue<ISimpleTask> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

@Override
public void start() {
    (new Thread(new SimplePoolThread(queue))).start();
}
```

Note that the queue from the pool was passed into the thread.  The thread then keeps a reference to this queue.  During the thread's run() it now also actually runs the task.

```
public class SimplePoolThread implements ISimplePoolThread, Runnable {


private LinkedBlockingQueue<ISimpleTask> queue;

public SimplePoolThread(LinkedBlockingQueue<ISimpleTask> queue)
{
    this.queue = queue;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Inserting Element: ");
        try {
            ISimpleTask task = queue.take();
            task.run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Inserting Element: 
1
Inserting Element: 
2
Inserting Element: 
3
```

..etc..

I assume this is for homework otherwise I would tell you not to reinvent the wheel and go use Java's built-in pooling services.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: Fantastic, this worked thanks! We had the constructor idea but needed the task.run in the while loop to solve it.